# Google Maps Geolocation API returns the latitude and longitude of my server

Tags: amazon-web-services, geolocation

During my testing the Geolocation API use to return proper result.
But in deployment on AWS it is returning me the IP address of Virginia where my EC2 instances are located.

"cellId": 27193,
"locationAreaCode": 17007,
"mobileCountryCode": 404,
"mobileNetworkCode": 20

Result:
"lat": 19.2019619, 
"lng": 73.1063466

But on AWs it returns:
"lat": 39.043756699999996 
"lng": -77.4874416

```
    params = {
        "key": SERVER_KEY
    }

    data = json.dumps({
        "cellTowers": [
            {
                "cellId": cid,
                "locationAreaCode": lac,
                "mobileCountryCode": mcc,
                "mobileNetworkCode": mnc
             }
         ]
    })

    log.info(params)
    log.info(data)
    request = requests.post(HOST_URL, params=params, data=data)
    # print(request.text)
    # print(request.status_code)

    if request.status_code == 200:
        response = json.loads(request.text)

        latitude = response["location"]["lat"]
        longitude = response["location"]["lng"]

        return {
            "latitude": latitude,
            "longitude": longitude
        }

    else:
        error_data = request.text
        log.error("Error Occurred in Finding Cell Tower Location")
        log.error(request.text)
        log.error(json.dumps(params))
        send_error_notification(error_data)
        return None
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer is so simple and how silly of me assuming that not adding header would not affect me.

By just adding the header with application/json everything is working like a charm.

```
    params = {
        "key": SERVER_KEY
    }

    data = json.dumps({
        "considerIp": False,
        "cellTowers": [
            {
                "cellId": cid,
                "locationAreaCode": lac,
                "mobileCountryCode": mcc,
                "mobileNetworkCode": mnc
             }
         ]
    })

    headers = {
        'content-type': "application/json",
        'cache-control': "no-cache"
    }

    log.info(params)
    log.info(data)
    request = requests.post(HOST_URL, params=params, data=data, headers=headers)
```